# How to get the content of an image throught url in php?

Tags: php, image, url

I am using an api of a SNS website, which is uploading an image. This api has a parameter "photo=photo_file_content", and is basing on **[RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)**.

Now I have the url of a certain image, but I don't kwon how to fetch the image, I've used `$param['photo'] =  file_get_contents($pic_path);` , but it didnt' work.

So what's the proper way to get the image? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you really need the content of the image?

Comment: @NirmalRam Hi, Nirmal. The api url is "http://api.fanfou.com/photos/upload.json" with POST method. The parameter is "photo=photo_file_content&text=...&callback=...", so without the content of the image, how can I post these parameter to the api? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use `curl` to upload the image?

Comment: Was typing it, you took my words @Barmar :-)

Comment: `file_get_contents` is proper enough. What is the proper way to post that image to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Client URL Library**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). It is the best solution for you.

Also, try this:

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $gm=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
```

and save the result `$gm` in a file.